# Email authentication using MERN stack get the message : "Internal Server Error"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, axios

First user can register and login with this code. But at the time of register of second user gives this error.

**The error is in EmailVerify.js in this axios.get(url) line.
Internal server error 500.**

These are the files and github code:

**github:** [Link Code](https://github.com/CyberW0lves/AuthInMern/tree/Email-Verify-In-MERN)

EmailVerify.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";


import { Fragment } from 'react';



const EmailVerify = () => {


    const [validUrl, setValidUrl] = useState(true);

    const param = useParams();

    console.log(param)

    useEffect(() => {

        const verifyEmailUrl = async () => {
            try {

                const url = `http://localhost:8080/api/users/${param.id}/verify/${param.token}`;

                const { data } = await axios.get(url);

                console.log("Data: ",data);
                
                console.log(validUrl)
                setValidUrl(true);
                

            } catch (error) {

                console.log(validUrl)
                
                console.log(error);
                setValidUrl(false);
            }
        };


        verifyEmailUrl();
    }, [param]);







  return (
    <Fragment>
            {validUrl ? (
                <div>
                    
                    <h1>Email verified successfully</h1>
                    <Link to="/login">
                        <button>Login</button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            ) : (
                <h1>404 Not Found</h1>
            )}
        </Fragment>
  )
}

export default EmailVerify
```

Register.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios, { isAxiosError } from "axios"
import {ToastContainer, toast} from 'react-toastify'
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

import styles from "./styles.module.css";


const Register = () => {

  const [data,setData] = useState({
    name:"",
    username:"",
    email:"",
    password:"",
  })

  const [error,setError] = useState([]);

  const [msg,setMsg] =  useState("");


  const handleChange = ({currentTarget:input}) =>{
    setData({...data,[input.name]: input.value});
  }


  const handleSubmit = async(e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const url = "http://localhost:8080/api/users";
            const { data: res } = await axios.post(url,data)
      // console.log(data);
            setMsg(res.message);
      console.log(res.message)
      
      setError('');
      toast.success(res.message, {
        position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT,
      });


        } catch (error) {
            if (
                error.response &&
                error.response.status >= 400 &&
                error.response.status <= 500
            ) {
                // setError(error.response.data.message);
        setError(error.response.data.message.details);
        setMsg('');
        console.log(error.response.data.message.details)
        console.log(typeof(error.response.data.message))
        toast.error(error.response.data.message, {
          position: toast.POSITION.TOP_RIGHT,
        });
            }
    
        }
  }




 
  return (
   
    <div className="flex min-h-full flex-1 flex-col justify-center px-6 py-12 lg:px-8">


        <div className="sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-sm">
          <img
            className="mx-auto h-10 w-auto"
            src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/mark.svg?color=indigo&shade=600"
            alt="Your Company"
          />
          <h2 className="mt-10 text-center text-2xl font-bold leading-9 tracking-tight text-gray-900">
            Register Here
          </h2>
        </div>

        <div className="mt-10 sm:mx-auto sm:w-full sm:max-w-sm">



          <form className="space-y-6" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>




      
              <label htmlFor="name" className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">
                Name
              </label>
              <div className="mt-2">
                <input
                  id="name"
                  name="name"
                  type="name"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={data.name}

                  required
                  className="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                />
              </div>
           




            {/* username */}

        
              <label htmlFor="username" className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">
                Username
              </label>
              <div className="mt-2">
                <input
                  id="username"
                  name="username"
                  type="username"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={data.username}
                  required
                  className="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                />
              </div>
           

            {/* Email */}
         
              <label htmlFor="email" className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">
                Email address
              </label>
              <div className="mt-2">
                <input
                  id="email"
                  name="email"
                  type="email"
                  autoComplete="email"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={data.email}
                  required
                  className="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                />
              </div>
            



            {/* Password */}



            <div>
              <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
                <label htmlFor="password" className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">
                  Password
                </label>
                {/* <div className="text-sm">
                  <a href="#" className="font-semibold text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500">
                    Forgot password?
                  </a>
                </div> */}
              </div>
              <div className="mt-2">
                <input
                  id="password"
                  name="password"
                  type="password"
                  autoComplete="current-password"
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  value={data.password}

                  required
                  className="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                />
              </div>


            </div>
                
            <div>
              <button
                type="submit"
                className="flex w-full justify-center rounded-md bg-indigo-600 px-3 py-1.5 text-sm font-semibold leading-6 text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-500 focus-visible:outline focus-visible:outline-2 focus-visible:outline-offset-2 focus-visible:outline-indigo-600"
              // onClick = {showms}
              >
                Register 
                  

              </button>
              <ul>
                {error && error.map((i,index)=>(

                    
                    <li key={index}>{i.message}</li>
                    
                    
                    
              )) }
              </ul>
              

             {/*{msg && <p>{msg}</p>}  */}
             

      
             <ToastContainer/>
            </div>

         

      
            
          </form>

          <p className="mt-10 text-center text-sm text-gray-500">
            
            Already a member?{' '}
            <Link to="/login" className="font-semibold leading-6 text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500">
              Login
            </Link>
          </p>
         
        </div>

        {/* <div className="bg-blue-500 text-white p-4 rounded-lg">
  {error.toString()}
</div> */}
      </div>


        
    
   
  )
}

export default Register
```

**In server side**

index.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const connection = require("./db")
const userRoutes = require("./routes/users")
const authRoutes = require("./routes/auth")


connection();    


app.use(express.json());

app.use(cors());



app.use("/api/users",userRoutes)
app.use("/api/auth",authRoutes)

    

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port,console.log(`Listening Port http://localhost:${port}`));
```

users.js

```
const router =  require("express").Router();
const {User,validate} = require("../models/user")
const Token = require("../models/token")
const crypto = require("crypto")
const sendEmail = require("../sendEmail")
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser")




const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")


router.post("/", async(req,res) =>{

    try{
        const {error} = validate(req.body);
        if(error)
                return res.status(400).send({message:error.details[0].message })


        let user = await User.findOne({email:req.body.email});


        if(user) 
                return res.status(409).send({message:"user with given emailid already exist"})

        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(Number(process.env.SALT));

        
        const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);

        user = await new User({ ...req.body, password: hashPassword }).save();

        const token = await new Token({
            userId: user._id,
            token: crypto.randomBytes(32).toString("hex"),
        }).save();
        
        const url = `${process.env.BASE_URL}users/${user.id}/verify/${token.token}`;
        await sendEmail(user.email, "Verify Email", url);

        res.status(201).send({ message: "An Email sent to your account please verify" });           
    
    
    
    }
    catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send({message:"Internal Server Errorrtee register"});

    }

})


router.get("/:id/verify/:token/", async(req,res)=>{


    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });

        if (!user) return res.status(400).send({ message: "Invalid link" });

        const token = await Token.findOne({
            userId: user._id,
            token: req.params.token,
        });
        if (!token) return res.status(400).send({ message: "Invalid link" });

        await User.updateOne({ _id: user._id, verified: true });
        await token.remove();

        res.status(200).send({ message: "Email verified successfully" });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send({ message: "Internal Server Error in users.js token" });
    }


})



module.exports = router;
```

.env style

**

> For privacy: values are not provide

**

```
MONGODB_URL =


JWTPRIVATEKEY = 

SALT = 
# SERVICE = 

# USER = 
# PASS = 

BASE_URL = http://localhost:5173/

SERVICE = gmail
SECURE =true

EMAIL_PORT = 
HOST = 

USER = 
PASS =
```

Sendmail.js

```
const nodemailer =  require("nodemailer");
module.exports = async(email,subject,text) =>{

    try {
        const transporter =  nodemailer.createTransport({
             host:process.env.HOST,
            // service:process.env.SERVICE,
            port:Number(process.env.EMAIL_PORT),
             secure:Boolean(process.env.SECURE),
            auth:{
                user:process.env.USER,
                pass:process.env.PASS,
            }
        })

        await transporter.sendMail({
            from:process.env.USER,
            to:email,
            subject:subject,
            text:text,
        })

        console.log("email sent successfully");

    } catch (error) {
        console.log("email not sent!");
        console.log(error);
        return error;
    }
}
```

**The second user also got the link through the email but when, click on the link the user directed to frontend but not able to verify.
Show: 404 error,**
This type of link user received
https://localhost:5173/users/${param.id}/verify/${param.token}

//More about Database

```
const mongoose =  require("mongoose")

module.exports = () =>{

    const connectionParams = {
        useNewUrlparser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology:true,
    };

    try {
        mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL,connectionParams)
        console.log("Connected to database");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        console.log("Could not connect the DB");
    }
}

MongoDB data structure:
```

*For the first User:*

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"useid"},"name":"poui","username":"jk","email":"user@email","password":"","verified":true,"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}
```

Comment: just like the first user, did the second user successfully receive an email for verification?

Comment: The second user also got the link through the email but when, click on the link the user directed to frontend but not able to verify.

Answer (score 0):

1/  I'd recommend using [prettier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettier) for the frontend code so it's more readable :)

2/ You can try add console.log("error", error, res) to understand what value you are passing to the backend:

```
} catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error, res)
    res.status(500).send({ message: "Internal Server Error in users.js token" });
}
```

3/ Double-check that the connection to MongoDB is set correctly. You can add logging to the db file to ensure if there are connection errors.

Comment: 1. Prettier already configured.
2.  MongoDB setup done
3. Error checked as many possible way
Every time at the time of login second user not not verified in database and send error with 500 as from EmailVerify.jsx